# Two controllers or one when creating an admin area?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When you use the `namespace` method to create an admin area, you are presented with these routes:

```
resources :stories
namespace :control_panel do
    resources :stories
end
```

gives me:

```
   control_panel_stories GET    /control_panel/stories(.:format)          control_panel/stories#index
                         POST   /control_panel/stories(.:format)          control_panel/stories#create
 new_control_panel_story GET    /control_panel/stories/new(.:format)      control_panel/stories#new
edit_control_panel_story GET    /control_panel/stories/:id/edit(.:format) control_panel/stories#edit
     control_panel_story GET    /control_panel/stories/:id(.:format)      control_panel/stories#show
                         PATCH  /control_panel/stories/:id(.:format)      control_panel/stories#update
                         PUT    /control_panel/stories/:id(.:format)      control_panel/stories#update
                         DELETE /control_panel/stories/:id(.:format)      control_panel/stories#destroy
```

Rails seems to be pushing me towards creating two controllers for the Story resource. One at `app/controllers/stories_controller.rb` and one at `app/controllers/control_panel/stories_controller.rb`

Should I use these two controllers? If I were to just use `stories_controller`, it would save a file, but it would be fiddly having to redirect back to the control_panel namespaced views in every single action if the user is admin. Should I use two controllers?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `controller` option.

Something like:

```
namespace :control_panel do
  resources :stories, controller: 'stories'
end
```

For custom actions use `actions` option

```
resources :stroies, actions: [:index, :show]
namespace :control_panel do
  resources :stories, controller: 'stories', except: [:index, :show]
end
```

So you can see stories without namespace, but managing them works just in `control_panel` namespace.

Additional, try [active_admin](http://activeadmin.info) gem for administration. It is easy and helpful

Answer (score 0):

If you have a [`namespaced` controller](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing), it basically puts it in another folder

There's some important inheritance stuff that goes on in the backend, but simply, you'll have another folder called `apps/controllers/control_panel` which you'll have to add the file to:

```
#app/controllers/control_panel/stories_controller.rb
Class ControlPanel::StoriesController < ApplicationController
   # stuff
end
```

This is different to your "standard" controller, which will just reside in the standard controllers section. [This is a great tutorial for you](http://iain.nl/backends-in-rails-3-1) to see how this works

---

**DRY**

You may wonder why you'd use this if it wasn't DRY

The answer is the two controllers allow you to perform different tasks / functionality. For example, in our admin areas, we use this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :stories, only: [:index, :show]
namespace :admin do
    resources :stories, except: :show
end
```

This gives us the ability to define the actions which each controller can perform (making it more secure). You can use `@asiniy`'s solution, but it will put all your code in one controller, which could be a problem